# Show the sum of detail grid rows in outer grid row in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, rowdetailstemplate

I have many rows in Kendo detailed grid and I am trying to show the sum of the detailed rows in outer grid's data cells. Is there any way I can do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created an example for you in this example i am showing total of first grid's columns into second grid's cell.

code:-

```
//calucalte the total of value column of first grid and create new data
var total=0;
var data=$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
$.each(data,function(i,row)
       { 
               total+=row.value; 
       });

//create dataSource for new grid
var source=[{"total":total}];
//create new grid here
$("#grid2").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: source,

    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                total: { type: "number", editable: false },

            }
        }            
    }, 
});
```

working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/mga6f/287/

thanks